# Use functions time in MySQL Stored Function

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I'm trying to create an execution log of a function stored within MySQL.

Have it like this:

Log table:

```
CREATE TABLE log_execution (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   task VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   start_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
   end_time TIMESTAMP(6));
```

Function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `log_execution`(p_task VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_start_time TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6);
   INSERT INTO log_execution(task, start_time) VALUES(p_task, v_start_time);

   SET @SLP = (SELECT SLEEP(5));

   UPDATE log_execution SET end_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) WHERE start_time = v_start_time;
   RETURN ROW_COUNT();
END;
```

But when I run it, the start time and end time are always the same, even if it takes seconds to run.

Does anyone know if it's a bug and how to solve it?

I'm using MySQL 5.7.40.

That when recording the log, correctly record the beginning and end of the execution.

Comment: Dude, your code is comments and your comments are code...

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` is a synonym for the `NOW()` function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now says:

> `NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, `NOW()` returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which returns the exact time at which it executes.